# Group by multiple columns with custom function

Tags: pandas

I do this:

```
join = lambda x: ' '.join(x)
df_temp = df.groupby(['Id']).agg({'InfoType': join,'InfoLabel1': join, 'InfoLabel2': join})
```

and it works.

Is there any other more efficient way (in terms of code lines etc) to do this?

For example I did this:

```
df_temp = df.groupby(['Id'])['InfoType', 'InfoLabel1', 'InfoLabel2'].agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
```

but this outputs only the `Id` and `InfoType` columns.

P.S.

Hm it seems that now also this is working:

```
 df_temp = df.groupby(['Id'])['InfoType', 'InfoLabel1', 'InfoLabel2'].agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
```

This happened after I converted all columns to strings - the columns contained NAs too.

I am having the impression that `pandas` was encountering some errors that it was not raising and it was just outputing the columns (i.e. 'InfoType') at which it did not encounter the errors).

Comment: `df.groupby(['Id']).agg(', '.join)` will work on all object columns

Comment: @Datanovice, cool but I want only these specific ones - not all the object columns of the dataframe.

Comment: are you able to add some data to reproduce your error/issue?

Comment: @Datanovice, I just edited my post with something I found ;)

Comment: you could try `df.set_index('Id').filter(like='info').groupby('Id').agg(', '.join)`

Comment: @Datanovice, ok thank you but the one above at my post looks more simple - the question is why it did not work before (eg because of NAs?).